# Animation not triggering after press on ImageView, but working fine after press on TextView

Tags: android, animation

In an Activity I have three Views (among others): a TextView, an ImageView, and a LinearLayout--the latter I call `controlsView`. There is a method (call it `toggleControls()` to toggle the visibility of `controlsView` with an animation.  The animation is fairly simple and is created each time the method is called, like this:

```
private void toggleControls () {
    if (controlsView.getAnimation () != null) {
        return; // already animating
    }
    if (controlsView.getVisibility () == View.GONE) {
        Animation animation = new ScaleAnimation (1, 1, 0, 1);
        animation.setAnimationListener (new AnimationListener () {
            public void onAnimationEnd (Animation animation) { controlsView.setAnimation (null); }
            public void onAnimationRepeat (Animation animation) {}
            public void onAnimationStart (Animation animation) { controlsView.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE); }
        });
        animation.setDuration (500);
        controlsView.setAnimation (animation);
        animation.startNow ();
    } else {
        // hide
        Animation animation = new ScaleAnimation (1, 1, 1, 0);
        animation.setAnimationListener (new AnimationListener () {
            public void onAnimationEnd (Animation animation) { controlsView.setAnimation (null); controlsView.setVisibility (View.GONE); }
            public void onAnimationRepeat (Animation animation) {}
            public void onAnimationStart (Animation animation) {}
        });
        animation.setDuration (500);
        controlsView.setAnimation (animation);
        animation.startNow ();
    }
}
```

This seems to work fine when called after a touch on the TextView, but when I call it after a touch on the ImageView, I never see the animation play.  Instead, the state of the view (as displayed) does not change... until I touch somewhere on the screen, at which point the `controlsView` will all-at-once appear or disappear.  (This is BTW on a Xoom tablet running Android 3.0.1.)

For completeness' sake, the mildly-simplified XML for the Views which are clicked:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/first"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="pressedFirst" android:clickable="true"
    android:text="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></TextView>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/second"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:onClick="pressedSecond" android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/something"></ImageView>
```

...and for the controlsView:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/controls"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible" android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button android:id="@+id/importantButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="pressedFilterButton" android:text="Important"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

The functions referenced in the above XML merely call the `toggleControls()` method.

I suspect I'm misunderstanding something fundamental here.  Would someone toss me a clue please?

Comment: style="@android:style/Widget.ImageButton" for ImageView works for me:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just throwing out a guess, but perhaps you need to call Drawable.invalidateSelf()? I know I needed to do that when an Animation wasn't occurring, but not sure if you're hitting the exact same problem.